# Excel formula to search for text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

i have a data set of which I wish to analyse.
I would like to search for the word "head" within multiple cells containing text strings in the same row e.g A2:G2 and then copy the contents of the cell which contains the word "head" into a specific cell destination A1.

Comment: `vlookup`? `search`? `index/match`?

Comment: What about those functions findwindow?

Comment: @ForwardEd without knowing what the cell contains or the layout of the data, it's hard to determine which function is appropriate but one of those should work.

Comment: yes, but without telling the person why you are asking about functions, it may be hard for them to know that you are asking for more information.

Comment: I am not asking them for more information. I am subtly telling them to research said functions and figure it out for themselves.

Comment: if they did not include it in the initial question then your subtle hint is probably too subtle.

Comment: lol yes. People who ask such questions care not for hints, no matter how subtle or otherwise.

Comment: mind you, you did leave the door open for the other approach:  "If at first you don't succeed, grab a bigger hammer"

Comment: @ForwardEd if the question needed to be asked as to which method the OP is using - then the question is either too broad and/or shows lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(A2:G2,MATCH("*head*",A2:G2,0))
```

Starting with the inner function, Match is looking for the word head contained anywhere within a cell in the range A2:G2.  The 0 tell match to look for an exact match.  Match return the position in the range A2:G2, which index then uses to determine which cell address to use to display the information in the cell where this formula is placed.  So in other words, put the above formula in A1.

One minor caveat, if the range A2:G2 had the word head in more than one place, it will return the left most position only.

Proof of Concept

[image]

OR as Scott Craner points out a more concise method:

```
=HLOOKUP("*head*",A2:G2,1,FALSE)
```

Comment: `filangies` that made me laugh.

Comment: apparently the correct spelling is phalanges.  oh well  I am an EnGineer (pronounce with hard G) not an arts major!

Comment: Now I am laughing harder, I thought it was on purpose.

Comment: Uh, you mean English major?

Comment: English is ONE of the arts degrees where spelling is VERY important.

Comment: Huh. You consider English art? Literature perhaps.

Comment: @findwindow anything outside the Sciences and/or Business is an Art degree. :)

Comment: universities hand out arts degrees for English, History, etc so yes, its an arts degree

Comment: @ScottCraner oohhhh snap

Comment: @ForwardEd oh. No idea^^;

Comment: The one I find funny is a Bachelor of Applied Science (Engineering) and a Bachelor of Engineering are both engineering degrees.

Comment: I don't get it. (not an engineer)

Comment: Oh and BTW, a little less typing `=HLOOKUP("*head*",A2:G2,1,FALSE)`

Comment: I dont get it either and I am an engineer.  The city I got my degree in has two universities in it.  They both offer engineering degree programs.  One gives a Bachelor of Applied Science (Engineering) [B.ASc.], and the other gives a Bachelor of Engineering [B.Eng.]  So its not like its a difference due to countries

Comment: Maybe applied science is more broad?